# Why don't you add a s at the end of word

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to coding so just trying to understand what the reason is, so sorry if this is a dumb quesstion, i have noticed the same thing with nums, why is it that in the code you don't put s end of word or if it were nums you remove the s, example of code below, does JS recognise name of words and nums differently?

```
const words = ['unique', 'uncanny', 'pique', 'oxymoron', 'guise'];

// Something is missing in the method call below

console.log(words.some(word => {
  return word.length < 6;
}));

// Use filter to create a new array
const interestingWords = words.filter((word) => {return word.length > 5});


// Make sure to uncomment the code below and fix the incorrect code before running it

console.log(interestingWords.every((word) => {return word.length > 5}));
```

Comment: `(word) => { ...functiondefinition...}` This is a function definition.  `(word)` is just its argument, it could have been changed from "word" to "hat" in all instances, and still work.

Comment: `word` and `words` are different identifiers. They might as well be called `yellow` and `carrot` - there is no actual relation between the two. Identifiers only matter to themselves, there is no "relations" at all based on name. However, names help us as developers to think about them - `words` is for many elements and each of those is a `word`.

Comment: It would be a similar situation if I used the variable `items` as a list, and then use `item` to refer to a specific item within the list.

Comment: `word` is a variable for method/function `some` on Array `words`, but it can be anything legal variable name.
`word` was chosen because `words` contains, well, words.
Here's a confusing bit of code:
`var blue="red"; var green=blue;` results in `green=="red"`...

Comment: so why is it when i change word to words it throws back a error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is conventional. We (as developers) used to write `words` (or anything with S) if the variable is an array, containing several words (or anything(s)).
If you want to iterate through the array `words`, it is common to use `word` to talk about every word in the array.

For example, this will print every value inside the array `words`:

```
words.forEach(word => console.log(word));
```

You can write this version as well, which is the same but more confusing:

```
words.forEach(duck => console.log(duck));
```

Comment: Grammar humor: "containing several words (or anything)" should be "containing several words (or anythings)"... :)

Answer (score 0):

Words is an array of strings
Then in the console.log, what’s happening is

```
words.some(word => {...});
```

here we call the some function on words array, and it takes in a callback function, which we have written using lambda expression. Basically the some function takes in a function that it will call for each element in the array.
So simplifying:

```
words.some(function(word) {...} );
```

you can see here that word and words are different, word is a parameter to the function. We can name it anything, it’s just that it represents the element of the array. I could have named it element, then in the method body done:

```
return element.length < 6;
```

But word is a good variable name since we have words array, and word represents the elements in the array. Similarly if we have numbers array, I would name the parameter in the callback function as number or num. it’s just a naming convention nothing else.

Comment: so if i change word to words why does it through back a error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the parameter for words.some(), and words.filter().
We can use a function that will run repeatedly with a parameter(It will be each item of the sequence).
So the name of the parameter could be whatever.
'word', 'each', 'item'...
words.some(function(each){return..}), words.filter(function(item){return..})

Answer (score 0):

This is just conventional coding. You could write anything there and it'll work. In your example, we use "word" because it makes the most sense to us, but you could put anything there.

Comment: so why when i change word to words it throws back an error in the code?